# grep with optional preceding segment

Tags: perl, grep

I have a search query `$x` in a perl script that I would like to find using a system `grep` command. However, not only do I wish to find `^$x` (i.e., anchored to the beginning of the line), but also the set `substr($x,-$y)` where `$y` ranges from `$z` to `length($x)`. How can such a `grep` operation be performed?

In case that description is unclear, I have constructed a toy example of the problem. Assuming that `$x=ABCDEFGH` and that `$z=3`, I wish to find the set of expressions comprising `^FGH` (`$y=-3=-$z`), `^EFGH` (`$y=-4`), `^DEFGH` (`$y=-5`), `^CDEFGH` (`$y=-6`), `^BCDEFGH` (`$y=-7`), and `^ABCDEFGH` (`$y=-8=-length($x)`).

Thus, from the following file:

```
ABCDEFGH    [1]
ZABCDEFGH   [2]
EFGHUBZ     [3]
EFGDEB      [4]
FGABC       [5]
DEFGHEDBD   [6]
DEFGJEFGHO  [7]
```

the lines returned would be 1, 3, and 6. Lines 2 and 7 would not be returned because the pattern is not anchored to the beginning of the line. Lines 4 and 5 would not be returned because the minimum sub-string required (`^FGH`) is not present.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Build a dynamic regex

The following dynamically builds a regex based off your search criteria:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Search Criteria
my $search = 'ABCDEFGH';
my $min = 3;

# Build regex according to spec
my $regex = '^(?:' . join('|', $search =~ /(?=(.{$min,})$)/g) . ')';

# Search through DATA
while (<DATA>) {
    print if $_ =~ $regex;
}

__DATA__
ABCDEFGH    [1]
ZABCDEFGH   [2]
EFGHUBZ     [3]
EFGDEB      [4]
FGABC       [5]
DEFGHEDBD   [6]
DEFGJEFGHO  [7]
```

Outputs:

```
ABCDEFGH    [1]
EFGHUBZ     [3]
DEFGHEDBD   [6]
```

#### Observe what matched

One can also observe what it's matching by modifying the code like the following:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    print if s/($regex)/($1)/;
}
```

Outputs:

```
(ABCDEFGH)    [1]
(EFGH)UBZ     [3]
(DEFGH)EDBD   [6]
```

#### Alternative Solution without building a regex

If one picks a delimiter that doesn't exist in the string like `\0`, you can also just test to see if the end of the search string matches the beginning of the line like so:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    print if "$search\0$_" =~ /(.{$min,})\0\1/;
}
```

Comment: That's very clever. If you don't mind, could you please explain this part: `(?=(.{$min,})$)` ? I see that there is a range `{$min,}` where the empty second field, I guess, implies `END`. But I don't see what the `?=(. )$` part does. Thank you.

Comment: `(?= )` is a positive look ahead assertion.  It enables one to find matching patterns that overlap.  In this case it's trying to match `(.{$min,})$` which is $min or more characters at the end of the string.  The first time this pattern matches, it finds all the characters.  The second time it matches the full string minus one.  If you'd like to see what the pattern matches, just use `print "$_\n" for $search =~ /(?=(.{$min,})$)/g;`

Comment: Your solutions exposed me to many `regex` concepts about which I have now had a chance to educate myself (e.g., capturing groups, look-around assertions). I have a couple more questions though about the mechanics of the answer: The positive look-around assertion initially finds `FGH` (since it is lazy?) and would ordinarily discard it (since look-around assertions are zero-length) but because of the parentheses, stores it in a capture group. The search would end here but for the `g` which in this case essentially acts as a loop until all matches `.{$min,}` are found, which exhaustively ...

Comment: ... checks the entire $search variable? Does that understanding sound correct? Also, normally the command `$search =~ /.../` would only return true or false depending on whether a match was or was not found, and one needs absolute backreferences to the captured groups (e.g., `\1`, `\2`, etc) to write these into the list that is ultimately joined by `|` characters. Thus, I don't understand how the sub-strings `FGH`, `EFGH`, `DEFGH` etc. are returned rather than `1`, `1`, `1` etc indicating simply that matches occurred. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, regarding the second, equally clever, solution, I wonder about the reason you don't include a `^` character (e.g., `(^.{$min,}`). My understanding is that the `regex` engine will automatically start building `.{$min,}` from the beginning of the line and thus will be able to find any match this way, but in cases of lines that lack a match, the engine will continue to build and test all other possibilities, so one might be able to prevent testing these other possibilities and thereby speed the algorithm for non-matching lines. Also, why do you include the back-reference (`\1`) after `0`?